# a javascript app that return inputted word + words from a predefined word bank

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an app that returns inputted word + words from a predefined word bank I have already made an input field and an output iframe and word bank

```
var bank =["Apples","Banana","Oranges","Grapes","Strawberry"]
```

and a function to output

```
$("form").submit(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
      var output = $(".output").contents().find("html").html($("#input").val());
});
```

but don't know how to add words to it
example:
User input: Delicious

App Returns:

Apples Delicious
Banana Delicious
Oranges Delicious
Grapes Delicious
Strawberry Delicious 
my javascript and jquery skills aren't that great I just learned them about a month ago so help and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array function called map()

```
var input = 'Delicious';

var delicious = bank.map(function(item) {
  return item + ' ' + input;
});

console.log(delicious);
```